К чему тип `${string}-${string}...`
Описание
Очень давно заметил, что crypto.randomUUID(); возвращает тип `${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}`.

Не понимал зачем этот тип, а не просто string и как его использовать.
Вчера, когда узнал про теговые шаблоны, понял, что вероятнее всего тип связан с ними.
Написал тег:
function join(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...parts: string[]): string {
    return parts.join('');
}

Теперь пытаюсь использовать его вместе с типом:
const uuid = crypto.randomUUID();

join uuid; // Unexpected keyword or identifier.
(join)uuid // ';' expected.
join(uuid) // Argument of type '`${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}`' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
join`${uuid}` // передается вся строка как первый параметр
join[uuid] // делает совершенно другое
[join]uuid // ';' expected
joinuuid // (¬_¬ )

Вопрос
Как это использовать?
А если я неправильно понял значение типа  `${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}`, то зачем она?

тип показывает что это не просто строка, а строка состоящая из 5 блоков разделенных -

@Grundy а программисту от этой информации какая польза? Ну как бы той же логикой могли бы показать, что Math.trunc возвращает не просто число а число, у которого нету дробной части.

И это было бы здорово, если бы ты мог показать, что Math.trunc возвращает не просто число а число, у которого нету дробной части, но сейчас этого нельзя сделать

а программисту от этой информации какая польза? - точно такая же, как и от любого другого специализированного типа.

@Grundy как по мне, слишком маленькая деталь, чтобы создать отдельный тип и поддерживать его... ну ладно :)

Просто пока у тебя не было задачи, когда твоя функция должна принимать строку в конкретном формате

@Grundy приведите для него пример)

@Grundy у меня было такой задачи, просто это решается одним Regex-ом.

ты не в ту сторону смотришь. Типы нужны для проверки корректности до запуска. регулярным выражением ты сможешь проверить формат только во время выполнения ¯\(ツ)/¯

@Grundy ну тогда, да - не было :)
